# Prevent field modification with Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Is there any way to set a field with an "unmodifiable" setting (Such as type, required, etc.) when you define a new Mongoose Schema? This means that once a new document is created, this field can't be changed.

For example, something like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unmodifiable: true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 34):

From version 5.6.0 of Mongoose, we can use `immutable: true` in schemas (exactly as the aforementioned answer on `mongoose-immutable` package).  Typical use case is for timestamps, but in your case, with `username` it goes like this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    immutable: true
  }
});
```

If you try to update the field, modification will be ignored by Mongoose.

---

Going a little further than what have been asked by OP, now with Mongoose 5.7.0 we can conditionally set the `immutable` property.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    immutable: doc => doc.role !== 'ADMIN'
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'USER',
    enum: ['USER', 'MODERATOR', 'ADMIN'],
    immutable: true
  }
});
```

Sources: [What's New in Mongoose 5.6.0: Immutable Properties](http://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-5-6-immutable-properties.html) and [What's New in Mongoose 5.7: Conditional Immutability, Faster Document Arrays](http://thecodebarbarian.com/mongoose-5-7-conditional-immutability-document-array-perf.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Mongoose only, in `userSchema.pre` `save`:

```
if (this.isModified('modified query')) {
    return next(new Error('Trying to modify restricted data'));
}
return next();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that the documentation explicitly states that when using functions with update in their identifier/name, the 'pre' middleware is not triggered:

> Although values are casted to their appropriate types when using update, the following are not applied:
>   - defaults
>   - setters
>   - validators
>   - middleware
>
> If you need those features, use the traditional approach of first retrieving the document.
>
> `Model.findOne({ name: 'borne' }, function (err, doc) {
>       if (err) ..
>       doc.name = 'jason bourne';
>       doc.save(callback);
>       })`

Therefore either go with the above way by mongooseAPI, which can trigger middleware (like 'pre' in [desoares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545155/7074015) answer) or triggers your own validators e.g.:

```
const theOneAndOnlyName = 'Master Splinter';
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: theOneAndOnlyName
    validate: {
      validator: value => {
        if(value != theOneAndOnlyName) {
          return Promise.reject('{{PATH}} do not specify this field, it will be set automatically');
          // message can be checked at error.errors['username'].reason
        }
        return true;
      },
      message: '{{PATH}} do not specify this field, it will be set automatically'
    }
  }
});
```

or always call any update functions (e.g. 'findByIdAndUpdate' and friends) with an additional 'options' argument in the form of `{ runValidators: true }` e.g.:

```
const splinter = new User({ username: undefined });
User.findByIdAndUpdate(splinter._id, { username: 'Shredder' }, { runValidators: true })
  .then(() => User.findById(splinter._id))
  .then(user => {
    assert(user.username === 'Shredder');

    done();
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error.errors['username'].reason));
```

You can also use the validator function in a non-standard way i.e.:

```
...
validator: function(value) {
  if(value != theOneAndOnlyName) {
    this.username = theOneAndOnlyName;
  }
  return true;
}
...
```

This does not throw a 'ValidationError' but quietly overrides the specified value. It still only does so, when using `save()` or update functions with specified validation option argument.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with field modifications.

Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-immutable-plugin

The plugin will reject each modification-attempt on a field and it works for

1. Update
2. UpdateOne
3. FindOneAndUpdate
4. UpdateMany
5. Re-save

It supports array, nesting objects, etc. types of field and guards deep immutability.

Plugin also handles update-options as $set, $inc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mongoose Immutable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-immutable). It's a small package you can install with the command below, it allows you to use the "immutable" property.

```
npm install mongoose-immutable --save
```

then to use it:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        immutable: true
    }
});
userSchema.plugin(immutablePlugin);
```